# How can the Ctrl+0 through Ctrl+9 key bindings be mapped in Vim?

Tags: vim

Why can’t I map—using any of the `*map` commands (`nmap`, `imap`, etc.)—the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> key strokes? In fact, it appears that some of them, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, are bound to `^[` at the X Window level. How can I make Vim override those default bindings?

That is, if I do `imap <C-3> fancystuffhere`, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> in Insert mode puts me into Normal mode, instead of inserting 'fancystuffhere'.

I’m using X11 on Linux.

Comment: this guy, ben frain,  seems like he may have got it to work though as of yet, i can't .  https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a . though some of his things seem superfluous 'cos ctrl-k is already gk

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both Vim and gVim use byte queue instead of keypress event queue, so that values from 0x40 (`@`) to 0x5F (`_`), including the 0x41–0x5A (`A`–`Z`) range) have corresponding control characters (you can get their codes by subtracting 0x40 from their value). Because of this, no characters above and beyond this range can be used together with `C-` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).

It is also the reason why `C-S-` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) for alphanumeric keys does not work even in gVim—functional keys generate more then one byte, so `<C-S-F1>` may work. Replacing `<C-3>` with `<Esc>` is done by terminal; you can try mapping it in almost any GUI application and see that `<Esc>` does not get mapped.

Comment: I cannot get these bindings work in OS X El Capitan. Should they work in the environment? I extended the thread here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235623/15504

Comment: @Masi Is not my answer clearly stating that they do not work *by design*? In Neovim you can map them (though it will not make them actually work, you need to tell terminal emulator to output specific escape sequences), but in Vim it *never* works.

Comment: I expanded the topic about Gvim with stereo keybindings in OS X here http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7452/2923 Which terminal emulator is most suitable for the specific escape sequences? Will default OS X manage?

Comment: @Masi I do not have OS X, so it is useless to ask me about terminal emulator there. For linux @leonerd in Neovim gitter may or may not be able to help: he is the author of the standard that supports `<C-1>` that was adopted by Neovim. I know that konsole *may* be configured *at least* on *per-combo* basis (i.e. `<C-1>`, but not `<C-{digit}>`), but cannot even say whether it may be configured generally.

Comment: @ZyX, actually, you're answer is not clear to me that it's by design.  An additional, more accessible explanation about what this design accomplishes and the motivation behind it would be helpful.  from my POV, it just sounds like some implementation detail that prevents me from doing something perfectly reasonable in theory.

Comment: @Jonah The truth is that main reason is historical. E.g. Neovim (Vim fork) was successfull at implementing different encoding scheme which allows such combinations. Second main reason is historical, but on terminal emulators’ side: I do not think Bram will bother changing anything here up until terminal emulators will be able to encode needed sequences: new scheme is useless if you are not able to receive such sequences from terminal emulator in first place.

Comment: @Jonah @cespinoza most likely uses exactly terminal emulator: `<C-3>` are *not* bound to anything like `<C-[>` on X window level unlike he is claiming, it is terminal emulator which does the transformation.

Comment: @Jonah Again, there is encoding scheme for terminal emulators designed specifically to keep some backward compatibility and yet allow numerous key combinations that are not allowed in the meantime. But it would be rather uneasy to convince their authors to implement it even as an option; and I am unsure anybody is working on convincing them to do this now.

Answer (score 5):

The way I accomplish this on windows is to use Autohotkey and remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc. to  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.

I know you’re on Linux, so it doesn’t apply for you, but thought I’d mention it for anyone else interested.